# How to add a game menu

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a generic game menu with "start" to initiate the game. How do I go about doing this? Here is the code:

```js
var LEFT_KEY = 37;
var UP_KEY = 38;
var RIGHT_KEY = 39;
var DOWN_KEY = 40;
var SPACE_KEY = 32;
var HERO_MOVEMENT = 3;
var lastLoopRun = 0;
var score = 0;
var iterations = 0;
var controller = new Object();
var enemies = new Array();

function createSprite(element, x, y, w, h) {
  var result = new Object();
  result.element = element;
  result.x = x;
  result.y = y;
  result.w = w;
  result.h = h;
  return result;
}

function toggleKey(keyCode, isPressed) {

  if (keyCode == LEFT_KEY) {

    controller.left = isPressed;

  }

  if (keyCode == RIGHT_KEY) {

    controller.right = isPressed;

  }

  if (keyCode == UP_KEY) {

    controller.up = isPressed;

  }

  if (keyCode == DOWN_KEY) {

    controller.down = isPressed;

  }

  if (keyCode == SPACE_KEY) {

    controller.space = isPressed;

  }

}

function intersects(a, b) {

  return a.x < b.x + b.w && a.x + a.w > b.x && a.y < b.y + b.h && a.y + a.h > b.y;

}

function ensureBounds(sprite, ignoreY) {

  if (sprite.x < 20) {

    sprite.x = 20;

  }

  if (!ignoreY && sprite.y < 20) {

    sprite.y = 20;

  }

  if (sprite.x + sprite.w > 480) {

    sprite.x = 480 - sprite.w;

  }

  if (!ignoreY && sprite.y + sprite.h > 480) {

    sprite.y = 480 - sprite.h;

  }

}

function setPosition(sprite) {

  var e = document.getElementById(sprite.element);

  e.style.left = sprite.x + 'px';

  e.style.top = sprite.y + 'px';

}

function handleControls() {

  if (controller.up) {

    hero.y -= HERO_MOVEMENT;

  }

  if (controller.down) {

    hero.y += HERO_MOVEMENT;

  }

  if (controller.left) {

    hero.x -= HERO_MOVEMENT;

  }

  if (controller.right) {

    hero.x += HERO_MOVEMENT;

  }

  if (controller.space) {

    var laser = getFireableLaser();

    if (laser) {

      laser.x = hero.x + 9;

      laser.y = hero.y - laser.h;

    }

  }

  ensureBounds(hero);

}

function getFireableLaser() {

  var result = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < lasers.length; i++) {

    if (lasers[i].y <= -120) {

      result = lasers[i];

    }

  }

  return result;

}

function getIntersectingLaser(enemy) {

  var result = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < lasers.length; i++) {

    if (intersects(lasers[i], enemy)) {

      result = lasers[i];

      break;

    }

  }

  return result;

}

function checkCollisions() {

  for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {

    var laser = getIntersectingLaser(enemies[i]);

    if (laser) {

      var element = document.getElementById(enemies[i].element);

      element.style.visibility = 'hidden';

      element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

      enemies.splice(i, 1);

      i--;

      laser.y = -laser.h;

      score += 100;

    } else if (intersects(hero, enemies[i])) {

      gameOver();

    } else if (enemies[i].y + enemies[i].h >= 500) {

      var element = document.getElementById(enemies[i].element);

      element.style.visibility = 'hidden';

      element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

      enemies.splice(i, 1);

      i--;

    }

  }

}

function gameOver() {

  var element = document.getElementById(hero.element);

  element.style.visibility = 'hidden';

  element = document.getElementById('gameover');

  element.style.visibility = 'visible';

}

function showSprites() {

  setPosition(hero);

  for (var i = 0; i < lasers.length; i++) {

    setPosition(lasers[i]);

  }

  for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {

    setPosition(enemies[i]);

  }

  var scoreElement = document.getElementById('score');

  scoreElement.innerHTML = 'SCORE: ' + score;

}

function updatePositions() {

  for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {

    enemies[i].y += 4;

    enemies[i].x += getRandom(7) - 3;

    ensureBounds(enemies[i], true);

  }

  for (var i = 0; i < lasers.length; i++) {

    lasers[i].y -= 12;

  }

}

function addEnemy() {

  var interval = 50;

  if (iterations > 1500) {

    interval = 5;

  } else if (iterations > 1000) {

    interval = 20;

  } else if (iterations > 500) {

    interval = 35;

  }



  if (getRandom(interval) == 0) {

    var elementName = 'enemy' + getRandom(10000000);

    var enemy = createSprite(elementName, getRandom(450), -40, 35, 35);



    var element = document.createElement('div');

    element.id = enemy.element;

    element.className = 'enemy';

    document.children[0].appendChild(element);



    enemies[enemies.length] = enemy;

  }

}

function getRandom(maxSize) {

  return parseInt(Math.random() * maxSize);

}

function loop() {

  if (new Date().getTime() - lastLoopRun > 40) {

    updatePositions();

    handleControls();

    checkCollisions();



    addEnemy();



    showSprites();



    lastLoopRun = new Date().getTime();

    iterations++;

  }

  setTimeout('loop();', 2);

}

document.onkeydown = function(evt) {

  toggleKey(evt.keyCode, true);

};

document.onkeyup = function(evt) {

  toggleKey(evt.keyCode, false);

};

var hero = createSprite('hero', 250, 460, 20, 20);

var lasers = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

  lasers[i] = createSprite('laser' + i, 0, -120, 2, 50);

}

loop();
```

```css
#hero {
  /* background: #ff0000; */
  background-image: url("man-of-space.png");
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}

#background {
  background-image: url("space.png");
  /* background: #000000; */
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.laser {
  background: #00ff00;
  width: 2px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
}

.enemy {
  background-image: url("spaceship.png");
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
}

#score {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18pt;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
}

#gameover {
  color: #ff0000;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 160px;
  top: 200px;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="background"></div>
<div id="hero"></div>
<div class="laser" id="laser0"></div>
<div class="laser" id="laser1"></div>
<div class="laser" id="laser2"></div>
<div id="score"></div>
<div id="gameover">GAME OVER</div>
```

Comment: I ***strongly suggest*** looking at the editing capabilities of the stack overflow question system and editing your post. The code in your question makes it very tough for anyone that would be willing to assist you with your issue to determine what your issue is. Use the tools that are available to format your question in a way that is presentable to the community.

Comment: I am very sorry as i am fairly new to stack overflow . Thank you for your kind suggestion Ill edit my code.

Comment: No problem, just take your time. Learn how the formatting tools work with the site and then edit the post. You can always place the question on hold per say by deleting it for the moment. The site holds the content in limbo and once you have it formatted in a way that is presentable, you can then undelete the post. This will help to ensure you do not get any negative reputation hits against your account. ;)

Comment: BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! ;) The following may assist: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: I have reformatted it to the best of my ability. I hope it is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your game UI in a `<div id="game" style="display: none;">` element so it will be hidden when the page is loaded. Then wrap your start menu in a `<div id="startMenu">` element with a `<button id="startButton">Start</button>` that will be used to hide the start menu and show the game UI.

In your JS code you could wrap your game in a function so it can be started when you call it.

HTML:

```
    <div id="startMenu">
        <button id="startButton">Start</button>
    </div>
        
    <div id="game" style="display: none;">
        <div id="background"></div>
        <div id="hero"></div>
        <div class="laser" id="laser0"></div>
        <div class="laser" id="laser1"></div>
        <div class="laser" id="laser2"></div>
        <div id="score"></div>
        <div id="gameover">GAME OVER</div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
function startGame() {
    var LEFT_KEY = 37;
    var UP_KEY = 38;
    var RIGHT_KEY = 39;
    var DOWN_KEY = 40;
    var SPACE_KEY = 32;
    var HERO_MOVEMENT = 3;
 
    [...Your game code...]

    loop();
}

document.getElementById('startButton').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('startMenu').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('game').style.display = "";
    startGame();
};
```

Now you have a start menu (`<div id="startMenu">`) that you can customize however you like, and a game UI (`<div id="game">`) that will be shown only after the start button is pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Add more HTML would be my suggestion. Maybe make a `div` that has all the start screen elements you need in it. When the start function happens, set that div's innerHTML to `""`.

Example:

```
document.getElementById('yourDivIdHere').innerHTML = '';
```